# Making JLabel move across JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a barrel inside my game float downwards towards the sceen by itself, I've tried a few things and looked up some tutorials, but I can't seem to make it work. Maybe I am approaching this in the wrong way by trying to do this inside a paintcomponent()? Inside my JPanel I also have a car object that is an extension of a JPanel controlled by KeyListeners.

```
// this is inside a JPanel class that I made that's painting out the game


OilBarrel barrel = new OilBarrel();


@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    road.paintComponent(g);

    this.add(car);
    this.add(barrel);

    barrel.setBounds(barrelX, barrel.getBarrelY(), 150, 180);
    int carX = car.getCarX();

    car.setBounds(carX, carY, 800, 400);
    barrel.setBounds(550, barrel.getBarrelY(), 800, 400);
    while (true) {
        barrel.move();
        repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}



    // this is the oilbarrel class

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Image;

 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class OilBarrel extends JLabel{

int barrelX;
int barrelY = 0;

public OilBarrel() {

    setVisible(true);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/oil.png")).getImage();


    this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));


    }



public void move(){

    if(barrelY<1000)
     barrelY +=1;

}



public int getBarrelY() {
    return barrelY;
 }

}
```

Comment: Having a `while(true)` in `paintComponent()` is not the way. You should run a separate thread that calls move() then repaint at intervals.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm really new to swing and threads in general. I could set a counter for the while condition. Could you be more specific or maybe give an example about your thread idea?

Comment: Don't call `road.paintComponent(g);` - there should never be a need to manually call `paint` or `paintComponent` on a component, if you find your self doing this, then you are doing something wrong. Also, don't modify the state of other components within the `paintComponent` method. In fact, don't use components in this way for this type of job

Comment: @MadProgrammer What do you mean I shouldn't use componenets "in this way" ? could you please clarify? I could just add a road rather than paint it out i suppose. You're also saying I shouldn't modify the state of other components, but is it ok to for example call methods inside paintyourself that will do this? Thanks

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic Components require a lot of micro management in relation to their size and position (in particular), they are also self painting if treated correctly.  Compared to a pure custom painting route, they require more work to manage

Comment: Is there any reason you're looking to do this in Swing directly rather than using [one of the plethora of tools related to game development](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SwingUtilities.invokeLater when a thread needs to update the GUI.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    while( true ){
                        // queue on Event Dispatch Thread
                        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                barrel.move();
                                repaint();
                            }
                        });
                        try{
                            Thread.sleep( 100 );
                        }catch( InterruptedException ie ){}
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
```

Also, lookup Swing Timer. I think that may be better.

Comment: I would avoid the unnecessary complexity of a `Thread` in this case. `repaint` by it's nature is also thread safe

Answer (score 3):

Swing is single threaded, this means that you `for-loop` in your `paintComponent` method is blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing it from updating the UI.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details

The simplest solution to solving the problem would be to use a [Swing `Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), as it allows for a small delay to be scheduled off the EDT, but which triggers it's updates on the EDT, making it safe to update the UI from within.

Component animation isn't hard, but it does require a different work flow, for example:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private int xDelta = 1;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            label = new JLabel("*");
            label.setSize(label.getPreferredSize());
            label.setLocation(0, (200 - label.getHeight()) / 2);
            add(label);
            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = label.getX();
                    x += xDelta;
                    if (x + label.getWidth() > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - label.getWidth();
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    label.setLocation(x, label.getY());
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

As a personal preference, I would avoid using components for this job and lean towards a complete custom painting route.

There are lots of reasons for this, components are complex objects which require a lot of attention to detail.  It's also difficult to apply additional effects or transformations to them

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Rectangle box;
        private int xDelta = 1;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(null);
            box = new Rectangle(0, 75, 50, 50);
            Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int x = box.x;
                    x += xDelta;
                    if (x + box.width > getWidth()) {
                        x = getWidth() - box.width;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    } else if (x < 0) {
                        x = 0;
                        xDelta *= -1;
                    }
                    box.setLocation(x, box.y);
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.draw(box);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sure this is very relevant information for my question and a great answer. However for someone at my level it seems a tad complex. I did end up using a thread in the end and a run() method instead of doing it in Paintcomponent.

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic There are two examples, both do basically the same thing, one is moving a label, one is perform custom painting. You will find that in general, custom painting approach is more efficient (painting a single component as to apposed multiple components) and generally easier to manage. The choice, how ever is yours. Also understand that, Swing `Timer` is optimised in such away as it won't post new timing events onto the EDT while outstanding timing events are queued, meaning you reduce the risk of saturating the EDT which will cause rendering slow downs